# Deleting arrows of a Quiver (GAP/QPA)

Tags: gap, computer-algebra-systems

Given a quiver $Q$

```
Q  :=  Quiver(  1,  [  [1,1,"a"],  [1,1,"b"]  ]  );
```

I would like a new quiver $Q1$ deleting a arrow from quiver $Q$.

My attempts (trying to delete the arrow `a`):

```
Removeset(ArrowsOfQuiver(Q),Q.a);

SubtractSet(ArrowsOfQuiver(Q),Q.a);

ArrowsOfQuiver(Q) := Filtered(ArrowsOfQuiver(Q), r -> r <> Q.a);
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way of doing this in QPA:

```
gap> Q  :=  Quiver(  1,  [  [1,1,"a"],  [1,1,"b"]  ]  );                                                                        
<quiver with 1 vertices and 2 arrows>
gap> vQ := VerticesOfQuiver( Q );                                                                                               
[ v1 ]
gap> newarrows := Filtered( ArrowsOfQuiver( Q ), r -> r <> Q.a );                                                                
[ b ]
gap> newarrows := List( newarrows, a -> [ Position( vQ, SourceOfPath( a ) ), Position( vQ, TargetOfPath( a ) ), String( a ) ] );
[ [ 1, 1, "b" ] ]
gap> Q1 := Quiver( NumberOfVertices( Q ), newarrows );                                                                          
<quiver with 1 vertices and 1 arrows>
gap> ArrowsOfQuiver( Q1 );
[ b ]
```

The above can be used when `newarrows` is the arrows you want to keep in the new quiver `Q1`.

The problem is that the command `Quiver` does not take as an argument a list of arrows in a given quiver.  One has to convert it to the allowed input format.

We hope that these comments are helpful.

The QPA-team.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about the specifics of the QPA package, but generically the GAP philosophy is that objects stay mathematically the same and that attribute values (such as `ArrowsOfQuiver`) cannot change. Thus, one could not change the object $Q$, but would have to create a *new* object with the desired properties.

With the caveat of not having the package installed, I guess that

```
Q1:=Quiver(1,Filtered(ArrowsOfQuiver(Q), r -> r <> Q.a));
```

would do the job.

Comment: Thanks, but this command appeared the following error:
Error, no method found! For debugging hints type ?Recovery from NoMethodFound
Error, no 1st choice method found for `Length' on 1 arguments at /proc/cygdrive/D/gap-4.10.2/lib/methsel2.g:250 called from
Length( arg[2][1] ) at /proc/cygdrive/D/gap-4.10.2/pkg/qpa-version-1.29/lib/quiver.gi:430 called from
<function "Quiver">( <arguments> )
 called from read-eval loop at *stdin*:377
type 'quit;' to quit to outer loop